# Title bar window appeared briefly in the 2nd window and would disappear a few seconds

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0 64-bit) and running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I created a Virtual Keyboard with C++ for my project and it worked fine. But, whenever the virtual keyboard appeared on the screen, its Title Bar window would appear briefly (a few seconds) on the top and then disappear. Why? How can I make the 'Title Bar window' never show up?

On the attached picture: Clicked on the 'ENG-1X3546' button that would create another window which would display a virtual keyboard which was located on the bottom.
You can see a 'Window Title Bar' on the top and its "Window Title" texts are ' "Virtual Keyboard" is ready'. It would disappear a few seconds later. The top 'Window Title Bar' belongs to the bottom 'Virtual Keyboard'. I don't want the top Window Title to appear at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:
Eventually, I found this is an Ubuntu issue and has nothing to do with QT.
Here are how to solve this problem:

Open an terminal in Ubuntu.
Enter "firefox".
Enter into search "noannoyance" and select NoAnnoyance - GNOME Shell Extensions.
Change the extension from Off to On.